# Swift make method parameter mutable?

Tags: swift, syntax, immutability, mutability

How can I deal with this error without creating additional variable?

```
func reduceToZero(x:Int) -> Int {
    while (x != 0) {
        x = x-1            // ERROR: cannot assign to 'let' value 'x'
    }
    return x
}
```

I don't want to create additional variable just to store the value of x. Is it even possible to do what I want?

Comment: See the updated answers below, Swift 3 has deprecated your accepted answer.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

As stated in other answers, as of Swift 3 placing var before a variable has been deprecated. Though not stated in other answers is the ability to declare an `inout` parameter. Think: passing in a pointer.

```
func reduceToZero(_ x: inout Int) {
    while (x != 0) {
        x = x-1     
    }
}

var a = 3
reduceToZero(&a)
print(a) // will print '0'
```

This can be particularly useful in recursion.

Apple's `inout` declaration guidelines can be found [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID545).

Comment: Thank you very much!!!! I am stuck here on a recursion question. You saved my life.

Comment: Should use this with caution as this modifies variables outside function scope. Ideally you want to explicitly return the value you changed inside the function.

Comment: `inout` keyword should be placed between parameter name and parameter type like this: `func reduceToZero(x: inout Int) ` in current Swift 3 version.

Comment: Except this doesn't seem to work for closures since closures evidently only capture inout parameters by value (at least that is the error message Xcode gives me). I use @GeRyCh solution in this case.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for now, but its like using pointers in C. Would this survive another Swift version?

Comment: This is not a suitable substitute for removal of the `var` keyword in parameter lists. You should shadow the original (constant) argument with a variable: `var x = x` should be the first line of the function.

Comment: I wouldn't make a comparison to a pointer for the simple fact that you're not modifying an address that must be dereferenced (in C++ parlance). inout rather makes the behavior similar to a language like Java, which is 'pass by reference' and fully mutable. The Swift designers decided to make method arguments immutable as a guard, so bypassing this behavior has to be given a bit more thought (which you could argue has some wisdom).

Comment: This changes that Int outside of the function scope though which is bad and may cause unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Downvoting for the comment than `inout` is dangerously not the same as having a mutable local copy.

Answer (score 55):

'var' parameters are deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3.
So assigning to a new parameter seems like the best way now:

```
func reduceToZero(x:Int) -> Int {
    var x = x
    while (x != 0) {
        x = x-1            
    }
    return x
}
```

as mentioned here: ['var' parameters are deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164973/var-parameters-are-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-swift-3)

Comment: In this case, does it actually copy the `x` in the the new `var x`? Or is Swift doing something more efficient than that?

Comment: This works and is what I do, but it seems very awkward.

Comment: @Gomfucius Not a word about this in the Swift 3.1 guide. In this case (`x` fits in register) there is virtually no cost. If `x` is array, struct, or object that is mutated, then a copy almost certainly needs to be performed (unless the optimizer can analyze it inline and alias it).

Comment: @wcochran This is a neat trick, but really there's nothing special going on. It's simply eclipsing an input parameter with a local var copy. In the OP's situation it is a better replacement for `var` args than using `inout` which may have unintended side-effects, esp. if the var was a pointer.

Comment: So should we use this method or the inout method?

Answer (score 47):

For Swift 1 and 2 (for Swift 3 see answer by achi using an inout parameter): Argument of a function in Swift is `let` by default so change it to `var` if you need to alter the value
i.e,

```
func reduceToZero(var x:Int) -> Int {
    while (x != 0) {
        x = x-1     
    }
    return x
}
```

Comment: Why is this answer up-voted like hell? The other answer was placed before this one, and contains more information than this one.

Comment: /!\ Using var will create a copy of the variable passed in parameters. So modifying it won't modify the original value. Also `var` in parameters is very likely to disappear in newer Swift versions per  https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters-patterns.md

Comment: var keyword in method paremeter will be deprecated in Swift 3.

Comment: I think with Swift 3, we won't be able to do this anymore. We'll have to create a variable copy of the array and return that modified array.

Comment: This answer is the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077880/swift-make-method-parameter-mutable/36993835#36993835

Answer (score 18):

Swift3 answer for passing mutable array pointer.

Function:

```
func foo(array: inout Array<Int>) {
    array.append(1)
}
```

Call to function:

```
var a = Array<Int>()
foo(array:&a)
```

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if this is correct as the Swift ground is ever-changing. I thought this better than doing var array = array inside the function because that makes a copy (and doesn't actually affect the original array structure)? Is a better design approach to aforementioned var approach and then return the new mutated array?

Answer (score 7):

In Swift you just add the `var` keyword before the variable name in the function declaration:

```
func reduceToZero(var x:Int) -> Int { // notice the "var" keyword
    while (x != 0) {
        x = x-1            
    }
    return x
}
```

Refer to the subsection "Constant and Variable Parameters" in the ["Functions" chapter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_204) of the Swift book (page 210 of the iBook as it is today).

Comment: 'var' parameters are deprecated and will be removed in Swift 3

Comment: Not valid for Swift 4 and newer.

Answer (score 6):

There are some cases where we dont ned to use `inout`

We can use something like this if you want that changes/scope to be only inside the function:

```
func manipulateData(a: Int) -> Int {
    var a = a
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Swift5 with Functional Programming...

```
func reduceToZeroFP(x:Int) -> Int {
    x == 0 ? x : reduceToZeroFP(x: x - 1)
}
```