# Why does Microsoft Azure (or Swift in general) fail to update a variable to return after a table query?

Tags: ios, sql, iphone, swift, azure

I've been following the Microsoft Azure [documentation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-how-to-use-client-library/) on querying tables successfully (inserting, reading, and updating items into the database work fine), but at the end of a simple method, right off the docs:

```
func getAllEventIDs() -> [String] {
    var events:[String] = [] //this is to be updated
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let client = delegate.client! //boiler-plate for azure

    let itemTable = client.tableWithName("Events")
    itemTable.query().readWithCompletion { 
    //something about this query block might be preventing successful initialization to the events array
        (result:MSQueryResult!, error) in
        //usually error-checking here
        for item in result.items {
            events.append(item.valueForKey("id") as! String)
            //returning events here...
        }
        //...and here (almost) work, since Swift expects a return of type Void
    }
    return events //still empty
}
```

I [may not pass the array in as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077880/swift-make-method-parameter-mutable), since the `.append` function will mutate that array.

The returned value is nothing but the initial empty array.
However, this issue seems to stem heavily from Azure's query code block and not from Swift itself.

### A simpler example:

```
func returnValueArray() -> [Int] {
    var array:[Int] = [0,0,0,0]
    var num:Int = 3
    for var n = 0; n < array.count; n++ {
        array[n] = num
    }
    return array
}
```

This returns [3,3,3,3].
Again, not Swift's problem, but Swift may have manifested Azure's return issue.

How can I return the desired, updated array at the end of query method?
Is it possible to pass in a mutable array into the method, append values, and then return that array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked: "How can I return the desired, updated array at the end of query method?" Short answer: You can't.

This is a fundamental of asynchronous coding.

The `readWithCompletion` method is asynchronous. It queues your request for processing in the background, and the returns immediately.

Your `return events //still empty` code executes before your read request has even begun processing.

You need to refactor your `getAllEventIDs` method to take a completion block as a parameter. That completion block would be passed your events array. Then inside the completion block for `readWithCompletion` you would call the completion block for your `getAllEventIDs` method.

So when you call `getAllEventIDs`, you pass it a completion block that does what you need to do with the events array.

### EDIT:

I created a Github project called SwiftCompletionHandlers that illustrates this and how to handle it. It has a sample class `AsyncManager` which simulates asynchronous downloading.

https://github.com/DuncanMC/SwiftCompletionHandlers

It has a method that looks like this:

```
func asyncFetchImage(#imageName: String,
  completion: (
    image: UIImage?,
    status: String) -> ())
  {
    println("Entering \(__FUNCTION__)")
    
    //Simulate a network operation by waiting a few seconds 
    //before loading an image
    let nSecDispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3.0 *
      Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    let queue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    dispatch_after(nSecDispatchTime, queue)
      {
        () -> Void in
        let result = UIImage(named: imageName)
        println("Loading image in background")
        let status = result != nil ? "image loaded" : "Error loading image"
        println("About to call completion handler")
        completion(image: result, status: status)
    }
    println("Leaving \(__FUNCTION__)")
  }
```

It takes a filename, and a completion block. The completion block gets passed a UIImage optional and a String status message.

Once the download is complete, the method invokes the completion block (aka closure.)

Here is the code that calls this method:

```
  @IBAction func loadImage(sender: UIButton)
  {
    let theAsyncManager = AsyncManager.sharedAsyncManager
    println("about to call asyncFetchImage")
    theAsyncManager.asyncFetchImage(imageName: "wareto_blue_150x115")
      {
        (image, status) -> () in
        println("Beginning completion block")
        self.theImageView.image = image
        println("In completion block, status = \(status)")
    }
    println("After call to asyncFetchImage")
  }
```

The output of the println statements is key to understanding what's going on:

```
about to call asyncFetchImage
Entering asyncFetchImage(imageName:completion:)
Leaving asyncFetchImage(imageName:completion:)
After call to asyncFetchImage
Loading image in background
About to call completion handler
Beginning completion block
In completion block, status = image loaded
```

Note that the "Leaving asyncFetchImage" and "After call to asyncFetchImage" messages print before the "Loading image in background" message. Then comes "About to call completion handler", then "Beginning completion block".

So the actual async work doesn't even start until after the loadImage function has returned.

If you don't understand what I'm describing, download the project and try it out, then set breakpoints and watch it execute.

Comment: Awesome. I noticed that the return statement happened first. Thank you

Comment: Wow, thank you for all this help! I can't even upvote with 8 reputation points haha

Comment: Regarding asynchronous coding, do the methods in a tableviewDelegate follow a certain order as well?

Comment: I don't think they are documented to do so, so you code defensively and not assume that they will. However, it's a fair bet that the table view will have to ask for the number of sections first. Then, before it can do anything with a given row, it will need to ask for the number of rows in that section. After that, don't rely on the order of calls that you see.

Comment: I see you have >15 rep now, so you can upvote if you so choose.

Comment: Yes :) And I'm getting the hang of completion closures now. I'll have to refactor most of my client-to-database code, but it'll be a good habit for later.