# cannot assign to value: 'word' is a 'let' constant

Tags: swift

I get following error: "cannot assign to value: 'word' is a 'let' constant"
I can't figure out why this happens.
If someone could help me, I would appreciate it a lot.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var word1 = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    func writeWord(word: String){
        word = "Example"
    }

    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        writeWord(word1)
        label.text = word1
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in your `writeWord` method?

Comment: now i'm not sure if you know what you want to do here

Answer (score 37):

what do you want to achieve there?

```
func writeWord(word: String){
    word = "Example"
}
```

only way to do that is:

```
func writeWord(word: String){
    var word = word
    word = "Example"
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why this answer was down-voted.  It seems correct and helped me.  Maybe showing it as SWIFT3 would be helpful.

Comment: i'm not sure either, i think that original post was too confusing to know if answer have any sense. Have a nice day

Comment: answer is bit small but more effected thankyou bro

Comment: good comment, thank you.

Comment: this is decent.

Comment: Any one knows why it happened ?

Answer (score 16):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24078011).

This seems to solve your question **but only for versions before Swift 3**.

The parameters to functions in Swift are immutable/you can't edit them. ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24078011))

Also, strings are [value types—not reference types](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10). That means, quite obviously, that the parameter `word` is not a reference to the variable passed into the function.

In order to update a value, you would have to add a return to the function or have a class variable, `word`, accessed by `self.word`.

If you decide to return a value, you would do so like this:

```
func writeWord(word: String) -> String {
    var mutableWord = word
    // do stuff to word(?)
    return mutableWord
}
```

I honestly don't really know why you're trying to do so I'm just guessing here at what your aim is.

Do you want:

```
func writeWord(word: String) {
    word1 = word
    word2 = word
    word3 = word
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Actually I have more variables (word1, word2, ...). I want them to be empty strings unless they get passed in the function writeWord. When they go thorugh the function I want another string ("Example") to be assigned to them. Finally I want to use the variable word1 (which should be "Example") to do other stuff.

Comment: Thanks.. it is working in Swift 4 also.

Comment: You can use the same namespace `var word = word`.

Answer (score -5):

In Swift 2 you have to write method

```
func writeWord(var word: String){
     word = "Example"
}
```

instead of

```
func writeWord(word: String){
     word = "Example"
}
```

because the param passed in function are by default `let` that is constant and cannot change its value. To change param value you have to explicitly make mutable by making it variable.In Swift 3 you may not face this problem.

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0003-remove-var-parameters.md

Comment: it still doesen't work

Comment: [var parameters removed in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36164973/var-parameters-are-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-swift-3) **and are still `let`**.